# How to connect with EC2 window instance using Jenkins and install the chrome

Tags: php, jenkins, amazon-ec2, ssh, aws-sdk

I am working on a project where I am using the AWS PHP SDK to create the instance of Linux and windows programmatically and save the SSH key on the machine where my script and Jenkins is running.

With Jenkins I can connect to ubuntu instance using SSH key and can do everything, what's I want.

But the issue raised up how I can connect to the window instance using Jenkins and install the chrome on this window machine and some other software silently.

Comment: as far as i know you can do it that on windows host by:
 -   installing ssh server on windows, configuring jenkins step to "execute shell on remote host using SSH" and combine it with windows PSEXEC tool to install software
 -   or connect windows as a slave to master and configure it using "execute bat command" jenkins steps.

Comment: No, I am doing all this using PHP SDK or Jenkins, that's why I cannot install these PSEXEC or SSH tool manually on window machine. I need the solution to install these things programmatically or through Jenkins, not manually. Thanks.